# Alternative to mapcar lisp

Tags: lisp, powerset

I need to write a recursive function for powerset, but I can't use mapcar, loop.

This is my code so far:

```
(defun parts (L)
  (cond 
    ((null L)'(nil))    
    (T
      (let ((PXs (parts (cdr L))))
        (append PXs (add(car L) PXs))
      )
    )   
  )
)

(defun add (E Cs)
  (cond
    (
    (null (cdr Cs))
        (list(cons E Cs))
    )
    (T 
        (append(list(cons E (list (car Cs)))) (addE (cdr Cs)))          
    )   
  )
)
```

But the result for (parts ('1 2 3)) is:

```
(NIL (3 NIL) (2 NIL) (2 (3 NIL)) (1 NIL) (1 (3 NIL)) (1 (2 NIL)) (1 (2 (3 NIL))))
```

I found this method

```
(defun powerset (list)
   (let ((x (car list)))
     (if x
       (let ((p (powerset (cdr list))))
         (append p (mapcar (lambda (list) (cons x list)) p)))
      '(()))))
```

And the result for (powerset('1 2 3)) is:

```
(NIL (3) (2) (2 3) (1) (1 3) (1 2) (1 2 3))
```

But I can't use mapcar, and I cannot found the problem in my code, is there any alternative to the function mapcar?

Comment: Did you mean `(powerset '(1 2 3))`? `(powerset ('1, 2, 3))` should get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibile solution:

```
(defun parts (l)
  (if (null l)
      '(())
      (add (car l) (parts (cdr l)))))

(defun add (x pset)
  (if (null pset)
      nil
      (cons (car pset)
            (cons (cons x (car pset))
                  (add x (cdr pset))))))

(parts '(1 2 3))  ;   =>  (NIL (1) (2) (1 2) (3) (1 3) (2 3) (1 2 3))
```

The function `add` adds the element x to a powerset in this way:

1. if the powerset is empty, there is nothing to add;
2. otherwise, the new powerset is obtained by inserting or not the element in all the lists of the powerset, so by duplicating its number of lists.

The function `parts` builds recursively the powerset of a list, by adding, one of its elements at time, to the powerset constituted by a list containing the empty list (the powerset of the empty set).

Answer (score 2):

Problem: we must not use:

```
 (mapcar (lambda (list) (cons x list)) p)
```

Solution:

```
 (pairlis (make-list (length p) :initial-element x) p)
```

That is to say, we make a list of the same length as `p` which contains repetitions of the value of `x`. Then we "zip-cons" this with `p` using `pairlis`:

```
 ;; understanding pairlis:
 (pairlis '(a b c) '(1 2 3)) ->  { either: ((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3))
                                 { or:     ((c . 3) (b . 2) (a . 1))
```

`pairlis`, when given just two arguments (no *alist*) is essentially `(mapcar #'cons list1 list2)` in disguise, with the added restriction that `list1` and `list2` have to be of the same length, and the result can be in forward or backward order.